# Fetch values in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have dataframe as follows:

```
        A   B   
1   2   3   4   5
4   5   6   7   8
```

I am trying to fetch data from this dataframe in following ways:

```
print (file_dataframe.columns)

Index(['A', 'B', 'Unnamed: 2'], dtype='object')

file_dataframe_values = [cell for column in file_dataframe.columns for cell in file_dataframe[column].values.tolist()]
print (file_dataframe_values )

['3', '6', '4', '7', '5', '8']
```

Why it is starting dataframe from first values in first row?

When I am using following dataframe:

```
    A
1   2   3   4   5
4   5   6   7   8


print (file_dataframe.columns)

Index(['A', 'Unnamed: 1', 'Unnamed: 2','Unnamed: 3'], dtype='object')

file_dataframe_values = [cell for column in file_dataframe.columns for cell in file_dataframe[column].values.tolist()]
print (file_dataframe_values )

['2','5','3', '6', '4', '7', '5', '8']
```

When I am using following data frame as first row is empty:

```
1   2   3   4   5
4   5   6   7   8


print (file_dataframe.columns)

Index(['Unnamed: 0', 'Unnamed: 1', 'Unnamed: 2','Unnamed: 3','Unnamed: 4'], dtype='object')

file_dataframe_values = [cell for column in file_dataframe.columns for cell in file_dataframe[column].values.tolist()]
print (file_dataframe_values )

['1','4','2','5','3', '6', '4', '7', '5', '8']
```

Can anyone please explain this behavior?

Comment: I think python interprets unknown column(s) prior to the first named one as (multi) index in case you don't specify 'header = 1'. In contrast, If all are unnamed, python assigns 'unnamed' to all since a dataframe can't be made of index columns only.

Answer (score 1):

#### Don't judge a dataframe by `print`

In the first instance, you have a dataframe with a `MultiIndex`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]],
                  columns=['A', 'B', ''],
                  index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(1, 2), (4, 5)]))

print(df)

     A  B   
1 2  3  4  5
4 5  6  7  8
```

In the second instance, you have a dataframe with a regular `Index`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 6, 7, 8]],
                  columns=['A', '', '', ''],
                  index=[1, 4])

print(df)

   A         
1  2  3  4  5
4  5  6  7  8
```

When you extract columns, index and values from each dataframe, you will have different results. This shouldn't be surprising. However, it does require you to learn about Pandas indexing, which is a useful exercise in any case. The following sections of the official docs may be helpful:

- [**Indexing and Selecting Data**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html)
- [**MultiIndex / Advanced Indexing**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html)

Unfortunately, there's no shortcut. This is purely API-specific logic.

Comment: I don't have data index actually it's excel sheet data, it's considering it as an index. can I do something as it will not consider it as index.

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare, Use `df = df.reset_index()` to elevant indices to columns.

Comment: @jpg, I got it working by mentioning `header=None` while reading excel.